How to find out if hierarchical namespace is enabled or not using OAuth with Azure sdk for cpp
I'm trying to get account info to find out if hierarchical namespace is enabled or not. But if I use OAuth method, this function fails...
There is no official statement, or at least I did not found it, but this comment in the unit tests.
TEST_F(BlobServiceClientTest, AccountInfo_LIVEONLY_)
  {
    // This operation doesn't support OAuth-based authorization.
    auto serviceClient
        = Blobs::BlobServiceClient::CreateFromConnectionString(StandardStorageConnectionString());

    auto accountInfo = serviceClient.GetAccountInfo().Value;
    EXPECT_FALSE(accountInfo.SkuName.ToString().empty());
    EXPECT_FALSE(accountInfo.AccountKind.ToString().empty());
    EXPECT_FALSE(accountInfo.IsHierarchicalNamespaceEnabled);

    auto containerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(LowercaseRandomString());

    accountInfo = containerClient.GetAccountInfo().Value;
    EXPECT_FALSE(accountInfo.SkuName.ToString().empty());
    EXPECT_FALSE(accountInfo.AccountKind.ToString().empty());
    EXPECT_FALSE(accountInfo.IsHierarchicalNamespaceEnabled);

    auto blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(RandomString());

    accountInfo = blobClient.GetAccountInfo().Value;
    EXPECT_FALSE(accountInfo.SkuName.ToString().empty());
    EXPECT_FALSE(accountInfo.AccountKind.ToString().empty());
    EXPECT_FALSE(accountInfo.IsHierarchicalNamespaceEnabled);
  }

So my question is, how to find out if hierarchical namespace is enabled or not using OAuth?

You need to check the Azure storage account's hierarchical namespace is enabled or not using C++?

Please add error and Explain briefly.

Exactly that. If I use GetAccountInfo I receive "The specified resource does not exists"
Looks like when you are using OAuth the GetAccountInfo is not supported, when you switch to shared key everything works fine.

You need to authenticate with oauth to make this to get the getaccountinfo?

You have to authenticate using shared key if you want to use getaccountinfo.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-account-information?tabs=shared-access-signatures
This operation doesn't support OAuth-based authorization via an access token from Azure Active Directory/MSI or a user delegation SAS.

You can use some of functions, and if they throw exception you can figure out if it is on or off...

Check the below answer.

You can able to get the hierarchical namespace is enabled using Microsoft azure AD client secret credential.


How to find out if hierarchical namespace is enabled or not using OAuth with Azure sdk for cpp

You can be able to get the hierarchical namespace is enabled or not using Microsoft Azure AD authorization using client secret credential.
First, create Microsoft Entra ID application and assign Storage Account contributor permission to the resource group.
Portal:

Now, you can use the below code to get the Hierarchical namespace is enabled or not using C++.
Code:
#include <iostream>
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>
#include <azure/identity/client_secret_credential.hpp>
#include <azure/core/context.hpp>

// Replace with your values
const std::string tenant_id = "93xxxxd";
const std::string client_id = "aaaxxxxx-8e4c-778c4b657aef";
const std::string client_secret = "LxxxxxxmQame";
const std::string subscription_id = "zzzzzzzz";
const std::string resource_group_name = "venkatesan-rg";
const std::string storage_account_name = "venkat7891";

using namespace web;                      
using namespace web::http;                 
using namespace web::http::client;        

int main()
{
    try
    {
        auto credential = std::make_shared<Azure::Identity::ClientSecretCredential>(
            tenant_id, client_id, client_secret);

        Azure::Core::Credentials::TokenRequestContext tokenRequestContext;
        tokenRequestContext.Scopes = { "https://management.azure.com/.default" };

        // Get the token
        auto token_response = credential->GetToken(
            tokenRequestContext, Azure::Core::Context());

        std::string token = token_response.Token;

        // Set the URL for the storage account properties API
        std::string url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/" + subscription_id +
            "/resourceGroups/" + resource_group_name +
            "/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/" + storage_account_name +
            "?api-version=2023-05-01";

        // Create HTTP client
        http_client client(utility::conversions::to_string_t(url));

        http_request request(methods::GET);
        request.headers().add(U("Authorization"), U("Bearer ") + utility::conversions::to_string_t(token));
        request.headers().add(U("Content-Type"), U("application/json"));

        auto response = client.request(request).get();

        // Check if the request was successful
        if (response.status_code() == status_codes::OK)
        {
            auto response_json = response.extract_json().get();
            bool is_hns_enabled = response_json[U("properties")][U("isHnsEnabled")].as_bool();
            std::wcout << L"Hierarchical namespace enabled: " << std::boolalpha << is_hns_enabled << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::wcout << L"Failed to get storage account properties: " << response.status_code() << std::endl;
            std::wcout << response.extract_string().get() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

Output:
Hierarchical namespace enabled: true


Reference:
Storage Accounts - Get Properties - REST API (Azure Storage Resource Provider) | Microsoft Learn .
The above link discusses the REST API will be able to fetch the hierarchical namespace is enabled or not using Microsoft Azure AD Authorization.
